# Is there WinAPI function 'ExistFile'?

Tags: c++, winapi, function, visual-studio-2008

Are there any WinAPI functions like ExistFile(...) and DeleteFile(...). And if there is any how can I use them? 
Regards

Comment: One problem with testing for existence is that you don't know how long the answer is valid. What if another program keeps creating and deleting files while you are testing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PathFileExists function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Determines whether a path to a file system object such as a file or folder is valid.

[DeleteFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Deletes an existing file.

Both are pretty much straightforward, so is their use.

Comment: `PathFileExists` is an odd beast. It tests if a path refers to either a file or a folder. So it will return true when passed the path to a folder. Perhaps not what you want. `GetFileAttributes` is how I would test for a file's existence. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/23/5612082.aspx